# Angular Downloading data and storing it in a factory

Tags: mysql, angularjs

I have been working with Angular for some time now.  My question is simple, I have a database with multiple tables.  There is a clients table and around 7 or 8 other tables that contain information about that client that I need.  None of the data from these tables is too terribly large.  In order to reduce http calls, it was my thought to load all of the tables and store the data from each into a object stored in a factory.

So once a particular client is called, the http requests are made from each table and each are stored inside of a factory.  Then, when a user needs to access that table, its data is stored in memory as the http call has been completed at the outset.  When the data is changed, it can make a quick save of the table data and reload it again.

Most of the data is financial containing information about the income and asset categories of the client.

Question is .. is this wise?  Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I use nodejs as my backend so for me what i do is i request the data to nodejs and than return an object with all the required data. I'm not sure what difficulty you are having.

Comment: If you're using SQL you should left join them together since you said it comes from a user. That user should have an id that links all those tables together somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of the term factory is inappropriate as a factory is a creational pattern. What you are describing is a facade. It is reasonable for a facade to aggregate data for a client and present it in a unified manner.

So, a remote client requests some data. The server-side facade makes the many requests on behalf of the client and composes the single response.

You have mentioned about caching the data. If you choose to do so, you will need to consider how to manage the cache data for staleness, how much memory you will need, etc.

Comment: Thank you.  And, it works quite well.  The first page load is about 1 -2 seconds slower due to the download, but after that, the page transition are quite fast.   I am having any data changes update both the factory variable as well as a server update to keep the two in sync.